# Send multiple arguments in .then function

Tags: javascript, callback, ecmascript-6, promise, bluebird

In callbacks we can send as many arguments as we want.

Likewise, I want to pass multiple arguments to a `then` function, either in Bluebird promises or native JavaScript promises.

Like this:

```
myPromise.then(a => {
    var b=122;
    // here I want to return multiple arguments
}).then((a,b,c) => {
    // do something with arguments
});
```

Comment: pass object with properties

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply return an object from the `then` method. If you use [destructuring](http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html) in the next `then`, it will be like passing multiple variables from one `then` to the next:

```
myPromise.then(a => {
    var b = 122;
    return {
        a,
        b,
        c: 'foo'
    };
}).then(({ a, b, c }) => {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);    
});
```

Note that in the first `then`, we are using a shortcut for returning `a` and `b` (it's the same as using `{ a: a, b: b, c: 'foo' }`).